# Пытаюсь получить и распарсит json с помощью php из js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, fetch

```php
<?php
     $connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'mysql','mysql', 'lo');
        
     $respons['value_one'] = 1000;
     $respons['value_two'] = 2000; 

     echo json_encode($respons)

?>
```

```js
function fetchLoadPage(){
           
    fetch('../php/loadPage.php', {/////////////////// отправка формы
      method: 'GET',
    }).then( (result) => {

        result = JSON.parse(result)

        console.log(result)

    })   
};
```

Но выкидывает ошибку

```
VM81:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:230
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В js надо в промисе обявить что то наподобии этого

```js
function fetchLoadPage(){
           
    fetch('../php/loadPage.php', {/////////////////// отправка формы
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then((result) => {

        console.log(result) // json

    })   
}
```

На стороне сервера проверить чтобы отправлялся заголовок `Content-Type: application/json`

@Alexey Ten в коментариях дал ссылку, я подмечу что в документации по fetch достаточно подробно описан данным момент.